# How to properly use findViewById inside class constructor?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to apply an id to an ImageButton, but it crashes on the last line inside the constructor.

it crashes on the first iteration of the loop

this is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:onClick="makeMove"
    android:tag="0"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/white" />

  //imageView1 ... imageView41

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView41"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

ImageButtonClass:

I had to use MainActity inside the constructor because I couldn't access the findViewById method.

```
public class ImageButtonClass 
{

    int id;
    int arrId;
    String color;
    ImageButton imageButton;

    ImageButtonClass(MainActivity mainActivity, int id, int arrId)
    {
    this.arrId = arrId;
    this.id = id;
    this.color = "White";

    //crashes on next line.
    imageButton = (ImageButton) mainActivity.findViewById(arrId); 
    }

}
```

and the MainActivity:

I'm using getResources because of all the Ids in the XML have the same name with a different ending.

```
ArrayList<ImageButtonClass> mBoard;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mBoard = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 42; i++)
    {
    int itemId = getResources().getIdentifier("imageView" + i, "id", 
    getPackageName());
    mBoard.add(new ImageButtonClass(this,i,itemId));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageButton

Maybe you will see this exception.

ImageView cannot be cast to ImageButton.

Change your view type imageview to imagebutton or change type of ImageButtonClass-imageButton.